# How to install netgear ac600 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I am trying to install netgear ac600 on Ubuntu 20.04 and use it instead of my internal WiFi card can someone please tell me how to set this up .I even have the install disk if that helps any ?

Comment: A perhaps unfortunate choice of hardware. If you are not up to compiling the driver (not a task for beginners), consider returning or exchanging for another adapter. There are lots of great Wi-Fi adapters that work out-of-the-box.

Comment: well i dont have that option if you could explain how to do this im sure i can figure it out i have looked up videos and it is possible to do i just need someone to show me how please?

Comment: I did find [this](https://thealaskalinuxuser.wordpress.com/2018/06/27/using-a-netgear-ac600-a6100-with-linux-successfully/).